# Failed to install ubuntu kernel package

Tags: kernel, compiling, debuild

I have built Linux images, headers and tools using the steps mentioned in Ubuntu build pages. Following are the deb packages I got;

1. linux-headers-4.15.0-51-generic_4.15.0-51.55_amd64.deb,
2. linux-tools-4.15.0-51-generic_4.15.0-51.55_amd64.deb,
3. linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-51-generic_4.15.0-51.55_amd64.deb

However when I was trying to install that in my Ubuntu 18.04 machine, using "dpkg -i *.deb", I was getting the following errors.

```
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-4.15.0-51-generic.
(Reading database ... 75312 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack linux-headers-4.15.0-51-generic_4.15.0-51.55_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-4.15.0-51-generic (4.15.0-51.55) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-51-generic.
Preparing to unpack linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-51-generic_4.15.0-51.55_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-51-generic (4.15.0-51.55) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-tools-4.15.0-51-generic.
Preparing to unpack linux-tools-4.15.0-51-generic_4.15.0-51.55_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-tools-4.15.0-51-generic (4.15.0-51.55) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-51-generic-dbgsym.
Preparing to unpack linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-51-generic-dbgsym_4.15.0-51.55_amd64.ddeb ...
Unpacking linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-51-generic-dbgsym (4.15.0-51.55) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-4.15.0-51-generic:
 linux-headers-4.15.0-51-generic depends on linux-headers-4.15.0-51; however:
  Package linux-headers-4.15.0-51 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-4.15.0-51-generic (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-51-generic:
 linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-51-generic depends on linux-modules-4.15.0-51-generic; however:
  Package linux-modules-4.15.0-51-generic is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-51-generic (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-tools-4.15.0-51-generic:
 linux-tools-4.15.0-51-generic depends on linux-tools-4.15.0-51; however:
  Package linux-tools-4.15.0-51 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package linux-tools-4.15.0-51-generic (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-51-generic-dbgsym (4.15.0-51.55) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-4.15.0-51-generic
 linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-51-generic
 linux-tools-4.15.0-51-generic
```

From the errors, I understand the following dependency packages are not installed;

1. linux-tools-4.15.0-51
2. linux-headers-4.15.0-51
3. linux-tools-4.15.0-51

What are these dependency packages and how can I build those?

Following is the content of the "debian/control" file for linux-tools-4.15.0-34-generic

```
Package: linux-tools-4.15.0-34-generic
Build-Profiles: <!stage1>
Architecture: i386 amd64 armhf arm64 ppc64el s390x
Section: devel
Priority: optional
Depends: ${misc:Depends}, linux-tools-4.15.0-34
Description: Linux kernel version specific tools for version 4.15.0-34
 This package provides the architecture dependant parts for kernel
 version locked tools (such as perf and x86_energy_perf_policy) for
 version 4.15.0-34 on
 64 bit x86.
```

I know how to install kernel packages using apt-get , but my requirement is to build my own kernel from the sources.

Comment: Looks like you already built those packages. Example: For `linux-tools-4.15.0-51`, you built `linux-tools-4.15.0-51-generic_4.15.0-51.55_amd64.deb`. Seems like you have a few dependencies each package's control file to update.

Comment: Yes. Example:linux-tools-4.15.0-34-generic has a dependency for  the linux-tools-4.15.0-51 in debian/control file. I have re-edited the post to include the contents of debian/control file as well. linux-tools-4.15.0-34-generic  and linux-tools-4.15.0-51 are different packages?. I understand so when I look at the control file.